# iPadでaiboビジュアルプログラミングのプロジェクト保存できない

Tags: aibo-developer, aibo-visual-programming

iPadでaiboビジュアルプログラミングで作ったプロジェクトファイルを保存しようとしましたが、エラーになってしまいます。
どうすれば保存できるのでしょうか？

コメントフォローありがとうございます。
iPadは、iPad Pro（12.9インチ）
OSバージョンは12.4.1です。
ブラウザはChromeです。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: どのようなエラーがメッセージが出ているか、またどのような動作環境iPadのOSのバージョン情報など詳しく記述できますか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

aibo デベロッパーサポート担当です。

aibo ビジュアルプログラミングは、Windows PC または Mac でお楽しみいただけます。
iPad では、プロジェクトの保存機能はご利用いただけません。
その他の動作環境につきましては、下記に記載があります。
http://aibo.sony.jp/fan/visual_programming/#faq4

今後とも aibo ビジュアルプログラミングをどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

aibo デベロッパーサポートチーム

Comment: 確かにScratchでもできないようですね。ご回答ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

既に公式さんから返答がありますが、補足として・・・
PCの動作対象環境であれば、ビジュアルプログラミングで作成したプロジェクトを「プロジェクト名.sb3」ファイルとしてダウンロードすることができ、これを再度読み込むことで続きから作成できます。

※現状、作ったものを「ふるまい」として自分のaiboや他のaiboオーナーさんが実行できるようにアプリ等に登録できる機能はありません。（SONYさん、ここ早く！！）

※保管した「プロジェクト名.sb3」を他のオーナーさんに配って、ビジュアルプログラミングで読み込んでもらえば、そのオーナーさんのaiboに作ったプロジェクトを渡すことは出来そうです。試していないので、トークンやデバイスIDといった個人情報が含まれるかまで見れていません。（SONYさん、もし見てたら「.sb3」ファイルを渡してもよいのか教えてください)

Comment: ありがとうございます。公式ページのFAQ見たのですが、シェアは可能なようですね！Q : 作ったプログラムを他の人とシェアできますか？

A : プロジェクトファイルをやり取りしていただくことでシェアできます。